# How to make this functionality in modal window through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have bunch of li in html list.

ul
 li
  img
  .det
 li

I want to do a thing that when I click on popup then I will show a modal popup. I want a prev next button in my modal popup (want them in jQuery)

I have tried http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/316_modal/source/index.html

Is their any plugin or script that make me able to make this feture.I also want to set modal popup from the det data I have.

The .det is hidden container. it's only shown when someone click. Do someone have idea for implement plugin here to get feature that make me able to make functionality modal popup with prev-next button.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you have in your code, but on your .det li (in html), you can set a function onclick="popup()" and initialize your popup in a js function like :

```
function popup(){
            $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

            $( "#dialog-modal" ).css("display", "auto");

    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
    });

        }
```

(if your dialog is modal and named "dialog-modal").
Hope it helps.